# Google chart responsive

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization, responsive

So i have this function to draw a graph, i already changed it a bit to try to make the chart responsive, but im not being able to do it...

here is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
                //alert('aa00'~
                                    $('.error').hide();
                                    $(".buttonSala").click(function() {
                                      // validate and process form here
                                      $('.error').hide();
                                      var nome = $( "#nomeSala option:selected" ).val();
                                      var objeto = $( "#sensorSala option:selected" ).val();
                                      var canal = $( "#canalSala option:selected" ).val();
                                      var datai = $("#datainisala").val(); 
                                      var dataf = $("#datafimsala").val(); 

                                     //alert(canal);
                                       // Send the data using post
                                       var posting = $.post( "getSala.php", { canal: canal, dataini: datai, datafim: dataf, objeto: objeto } );

                                       // Put the results in a div
                                        posting.done(
                                            function drawChart1( data ) {
                                            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.

                                                $('.box-title').html(nome);
                                                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                                                var jsonData = response.channels[canal].values;
                                                var desciption = response.channels[canal].info.chname;
                                                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
                                                dataArray = [["ts", desciption ]];

                                                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    var tempArray = [jsonData[i].ts, parseFloat(jsonData[i].value.replace(",", "."))];
                                                    dataArray.push(tempArray);
                                                }

                                                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                                                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
                                                        dataArray
                                                        );                

                                                var options = {
                                                  curveType: 'function',
                                                  backgroundColor: '#fff',
                                                  colors: ['#5d4a50'],
                                                  vAxis: {
                                                    gridlines: {
                                                        color: 'transparent'
                                                    },
                                                    textStyle: {
                                                        color: '#666', fontSize: 16
                                                    }
                                                  },
                                                  legend: { position: 'bottom', textStyle: {
                                                        color: '#666', fontSize: 18
                                                    } }
                                                };

                                                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                                                var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                                                chart.draw(data, options);

                                                }
                                            );
                                        });

                                          $(window).resize(function(){
                                          drawChart1();
                                        });


                    return false;
                                    });

                                  });
```

Then on my css i already added this:

```
.chart {
  width: 100%; 
  min-height: 450px;
}
```

And my html is like this:

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="chart_div" class="chart"></div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

But the graph isn't responsive still... The div where the graph is being draw is responsive already, but when i resize the window, the graph inside just gets cut...

Any sugestions?

Comment: Can I suggest using ChartJS instead? I found it did everything that I needed and has a responsive mode built in. http://www.chartjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

*first*, you can rely on the `callback` from google to know when the document is ready,
instead of --> `$(document).ready(...`

and the `callback` can be placed in the `load` statement,
no need to use `setOnLoadCallback` every time the chart needs to be drawn

recommend setup similar to the following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var googleChart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var googleData = null;

    $('.buttonSala').click(getData);
    $(window).resize(drawChart);

    function getData() {
      $('.error').hide();
      var nome = $( "#nomeSala option:selected" ).val();
      $('.box-title').html(nome);
      var objeto = $( "#sensorSala option:selected" ).val();
      var canal = $( "#canalSala option:selected" ).val();
      var datai = $("#datainisala").val();
      var dataf = $("#datafimsala").val();
      var posting = $.post( "getSala.php", { canal: canal, dataini: datai, datafim: dataf, objeto: objeto } );
      posting.done(processData);
      return false;
    }

    function processData(data) {
      var response = JSON.parse(data);
      var jsonData = response.channels[canal].values;
      var desciption = response.channels[canal].info.chname;
      dataArray = [["ts", desciption ]];

      for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        dataArray.push([
          jsonData[i].ts,
          parseFloat(jsonData[i].value.replace(",", "."))
        ]);
      }

      var googleData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
        dataArray
      );
      drawChart();
    }

    function drawChart() {
      if (googleData === null) {
        return;
      }
      googleChart.draw(googleData, {
        curveType: 'function',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        colors: ['#5d4a50'],
        vAxis: {
          gridlines: {
            color: 'transparent'
          },
          textStyle: {
            color: '#666',
            fontSize: 16
          }
        },
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom',
          textStyle: {
            color: '#666', fontSize: 18
          }
        }
      });
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```